# How to increase the size of the webkit resizer in CSS?

Tags: html, css

The default size of the resizer is too small for some of my users to see. How do I increase its size?

I've tried using `::webkit-resizer{ font-size: 20px; }`, but it's not working. I can however change its background color targeting the same.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If someone provided a screen shot to you without code, would you be able to help them? This is impossible without seeing your code. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's **no standard way** to style the `resize` gripper directly, but **you can use a hack** to *increase it's **size***. If you `scale` up the resizable element, then compensate back down on the child, the effect looks as though the gripper is larger while the text stays the same:

```css
.parent {
            resize:both; /* make resizable */
            overflow:hidden; /* how the resizer */
            transform: scale(2);  /* Scales the resize up */
            transform-origin: top left;
            width: 50%;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
      
   
.child {
            font-size: .5em; /* Scales the text back down */
            padding: 1em
        }
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'>
      Scale UP parent div by 2.
      <br/>
      Scale back child font by 50% (.5em)
    </div>
 </div>
```